# Append word(s) any where in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm modifying a standard webcontrol in a system i'm working on which has some string values I don't have access to. I want to know if theres a way to append additional words to a string, anywhere in it using jquery.

Example:
Current string: You are currently accessing these settings as *Username*.

What I want: You are currently accessing these settings and system controls as *Username*

**and system controls** being the additional words I'd like to append to the string. How is this possible through jQuery?

Comment: This is more a job of javascript that jquery. Look at the string manipulation functions in your javascript manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that, simple JavaScript will suffice:

```
var myString = 'You are currently accessing these settings as Username.';
var newString = myString.replace ( 'these settings', 'these settings and system controls' );
```

What you are using here is the [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Answer (score 1):

extending on Jan's answer:

```
$("#control").text(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace ( 'these settings', 'these settings and system controls' );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something more like this ?
It's an update of Jan's answer

```
var cunstructVar = ' these settings '+' and system controls '+' ... ';
var originalString = 'You are currently accessing _TO_REPLACE_ as Username.';

var newString = originalString.replace ( '_TO_REPLACE_', cunstructVar  );
```

Comment: Good example. My issue is that I do not have access to the file providing these string, so I have to modify them through javascript. So doing this is out of the question but +1 for the example

Comment: I knew it was that when I put cunstructVar it's a var that get constructed by javascript that's why I put the concat ;-)